# Python 2.6 on Debian Lenny. Where should the executable go?

Tags: python, linux, debian

I am building python2.6 from source on Debian Lenny.

( ./configure make make altinstall )

I don't want it to conflict with anything existing, but I want it to be in the default search path for bash.

Suggestions?

(ps, I'm using a vm, so I can trash it and rebuild.)

Comment: Side question: what VM are you using, and are you happy with it?  I'm trying to decide whether to use Xen, KVM, or OpenVZ right now...

Comment: Just VirtualBox on WinXP now :)

Comment: I've never had any problems with OpenVZ

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's the purpose of `/usr/local` according to the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/).

> The /usr/local hierarchy is for use by the system administrator when installing software locally.

I think configure typically defaults to /usr/local unless told otherwise, but to be sure you could run `./configure --prefix=/usr/local ...`.

Comment: http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/ch-modify.en.html says to go to /urs/bin
I think this is a Debianism.

Comment: No, `/usr/local` on Debian as well.  That documentation is for maintainers.

Comment: That guide is about the work that maintainers do when they build packages which are uploaded to Debian.  That's completely irrelevant for a sysadmin compiling and installing software on their own unless they're building a Debian package to install.

Comment: @Jed Smith && @ jamessan ah, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend you do one of these two options.

- Build a .deb package, and then install the .deb package; the installed then go in the usual places (/usr/bin/python26 for the main interpreter).
- Build from source, and install from source into /usr/local/bin.

I think it is a very bad idea to start putting files in the usual places, but not known or understood by the package manager.  If you built it by hand and installed it by hand, it should be confined in the /usr/local tree.

Comment: Yes. I'm looking at using checkinstall

Comment: /usr/local is reserved in debian. 

per http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/ch-modify.en.html

Comment: Yes, exactly: /usr/local is reserved in Debian for exactly the specific use I am recommending.  That link you provided says that Debian packages must not put things in /usr/local, because it is reserved for the system administrator to put things there.  This is exactly what I said: if you want the files in "the usual places" such as /usr/bin, then build *packages* that put the files there; if you don't want to build the packages, and you want to install by hand, then *only* install in /usr/local.

Comment: It is reserver for _local installations like the one you are contemplating_.  In short: '/usr' is for packages, '/usr/local' is where packages will never install (apart from stubs as eg /usr/local/lib/python2.$Version/ so that you can use these directories).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to fetch the source package from testing or unstable and to rebuild it locally so that you get a .deb instead.  Doesn't backports.org have it?

*Edit:* Debian has python2.6 only in experimental, see [here](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python2.6). You could also take the source package from Ubuntu.

Comment: Python 2.6 is still in experimental, so it isn't available for a backport.

Comment: Ack. AFAIK backports are mostly one-off anyway.

Comment: backports.com does not have python2.6

There are dependency problems on debian stable. Working through these now.

Answer (score 0):

Your safest bet is to put Python 2.6 in `/opt` (`./configure --prefix=/opt`), and modify `/etc/profile` so that `/opt/bin` is searched first.

Comment: The FHS standard does allow for using /opt or /usr/local.  However, I have seen vendors provide Debian packages that install into /opt; so I have a preference for using /usr/local.  But either is permitted.  http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html